# play output sound from microphone cable from the speaker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

is there any code in flutter to play the output sound of a microphone cable from the phone speaker?
in real-time
I need a complete sample that work
thank you

Comment: There are definitely packages that you can use where you can probably get "real-time" with latency of course. You can usually get sample code from the package that you choose.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore can you suggest one?

Comment: [Flutter sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound)